# Poisson Bracket on non-smooth manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

It is known that any Poisson bracket on a smooth variety $X$ corresponds to a bivector field. What is the simplest example of a non-smooth variety with a Poisson bracket that does not correspond to a bivector field?

Comment: Please add your definition of a Poisson bracket on a non-smooth manifold. If it is a bi-linear map, then what is its domain? If you mean algebraic variety, then what does bi-vector field mean?

Comment: @RicardoBuring For simplicity take an affine variety $X$ corresponding to an algebra $A$. Then the Poisson bracket is just a map from $\Lambda^2 A \to A$ satisfying the Leibnitz rule and the Jacobi identity. You also have a notion of Kahler differentials and you have the module of derivations $T_A$, so you have a notion of differential forms/vector fields and you can take their exterior powers and therefore you have a notion of bivector fields.